# Android Simplecursoradapter not using the cursor i'm passiing

Tags: android, listview, cursor, simplecursoradapter

```
cursor = getContentResolver().query(GroceryItemProvider.ITEM_URI, projection, id+"="+GroceryItemTable.LIST_ID, null, null);
adapter= new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, cursor, from, to , 0);
adapter.swapCursor(cursor);
```

This creates a list with the entire table rather than the cursor I pass with custom values, is that the default behaviour??

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you are getting all columns of data or all rows of data? If you are getting all columns, then please mention the value of variable projection. If you are getting all rows, then you can limit rows by providing the last argument to getContentResolver().query() method like:-

```
cursor = getContentResolver().query(GroceryItemProvider.ITEM_URI, projection, id+"="+GroceryItemTable.LIST_ID, null, "id limit 10");
```

Comment: Cursor gets the correct rows but the adapter still uses the table.
I checked the cursor that it only contains the rows matching id+"="+GroceryItemTable.LIST_ID but the adapter still populates the list with all the rows of the table.

Comment: In that case you should call 
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after adapter.swapCursor.

Comment: i tried ur suggestion but it did not solve the problem, here is the code 

list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.item_list);
cursor = getContentResolver().query(GroceryItemProvider.ITEM_URI, projection, id+"="+GroceryItemTable.LIST_ID, null, null);
adapter= new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, cursor , from, to , 0);
adapter.swapCursor(cursor);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
list.setAdapter(adapter);